# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para poner por defecto un valor en una tabla que referencia de otra tabla?

Tags: python, web2py

Estoy trabajando con el framework web2py tengo un campo que esta como referencia a un valor de otra tabla, en la vista que se muestra sale en blanco y si le doy click recien muestra los valores pero eso deberíaa salir por defecto `Elegir Opcion` pero no está saliendo:

```
Field('moneda', 'reference monedas',default="Elegir Opcion",requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.monedas, '%(nombre)s'))),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es el parámetro `zero` del validador [`IS_IN_DB`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Database-validators):

```
Field('moneda', 'reference monedas', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.monedas, '%(nombre)s', zero='Elegir Opcion'))),
```

El atributo [`default`](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor) sirve para darle un valor por defecto a la relación.

La documentación es tu amiga:

- [Libro online en inglés](http://web2py.com/book)
- [Libro online en español](http://www.latinuxpress.com/books/drafts/web2py/) (Beta)